# I can't display mongoDB atlas data on other devices

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongodb-atlas

I have a news app uploaded to firebase, I have the database developed in mongoDB, investigating I found mongodb atlas that what it does is generate a link to reference the database, so far so good, I can upload and delete and modify files, when I deploy in firebase it takes the data that I uploaded (only on my device), the problem occurs when I try to see it on other devices I try with several cell phones and nothing, someone knows why it does not take me data on other devices?

I attach data to you.

> mi app noticias of firebase https://nnoticias-3000b.web.app/

**My Back-End**

index.js

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = require('./app');
var port = 3700;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://leandro:prueba123@cluster0-shard-00-00.mpgr7.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.mpgr7.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.mpgr7.mongodb.net:27017/noticias?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-i31fjg-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority').then(() => {

  console.log("Conexion exitosa xd");
    // Creacion del servidor
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log("Servidor corriendo correctamente en la url: localhost:3700");
    });
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

app.js

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// archivos de rutas+
var noticias_routes = require('./routes/noticias');
// moddlewares

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json(""));

// Configurar cabeceras y cors
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});

//  rutas
app.use('/api', noticias_routes);

// exportar
module.exports = app;
```

**Front-End**

global.ts

```
export var Global = {
  url: 'http://localhost:3700/api/'
};
```

my service noticias.service.ts

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Economia, Medicina, Politica, Tecnologia} from '../models/noticias';

import { Global} from './global';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class NoticiasService{
  public url: string;

  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient
  ){
    this.url = Global.url;
  }

  saveEconomia(economia:Economia): Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(economia);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');

    return this._http.post<any>(this.url+'save-economia', params, {headers:headers});
  }

  getEconomias(): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.get(this.url+'economias', {headers: headers});
  }

  getEconomia(id): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.get(this.url+'economia/'+id, {headers: headers});
  }

  deleteEconomia(id): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.delete(this.url+'economia/'+id, {headers: headers});
  }

  updateEconomia(economia): Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(economia);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.put(this.url+'economia/'+economia._id, params, {headers: headers});
  }




  savePolitica(politica:Politica): Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(politica);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');

    return this._http.post<any>(this.url+'save-politica', params, {headers:headers});
  }

  getPoliticas(): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.get(this.url+'politicas', {headers: headers});
  }

  getPolitica(id): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.get(this.url+'politica/'+id, {headers: headers});
  }

  deletePolitica(id): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.delete(this.url+'politica/'+id, {headers: headers});
  }

  updatePolitica(politica): Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(politica);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.put(this.url+'politica/'+politica._id, params, {headers: headers});
  }



  saveMedicina(medicina:Medicina): Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(medicina);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');

    return this._http.post<any>(this.url+'save-medicina', params, {headers:headers});
  }

  getMedicinas(): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.get(this.url+'medicinas', {headers: headers});
  }

  getMedicina(id): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.get(this.url+'medicina/'+id, {headers: headers});
  }

  deleteMedicina(id): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.delete(this.url+'medicina/'+id, {headers: headers});
  }

  updateMedicina(medicina): Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(medicina);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this._http.put(this.url+'medicina/'+medicina._id, params, {headers: headers});
  }



    saveTecnologia(tecnologia:Tecnologia): Observable<any>{
      let params = JSON.stringify(tecnologia);
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');

      return this._http.post<any>(this.url+'save-tecnologia', params, {headers:headers});
    }

    getTecnologias(): Observable<any>{
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      return this._http.get(this.url+'tecnologias', {headers: headers});
    }

    getTecnologia(id): Observable<any>{
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      return this._http.get(this.url+'tecnologia/'+id, {headers: headers});
    }

    deleteTecnologia(id): Observable<any>{
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      return this._http.delete(this.url+'tecnologia/'+id, {headers: headers});
    }

    updateTecnologia(tecnologia): Observable<any>{
      let params = JSON.stringify(tecnologia);
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      return this._http.put(this.url+'tecnologia/'+tecnologia._id, params, {headers: headers});
    }


}
```

extra data ...

*1. my backend and my front are in separate folders*

*2.  to see the content that I uploaded to firebase I have to have the command npm start*

*3. I think the problem is that I never leave the localhost*

Comment: sorry, i thought i was in stackOverflow español

Comment: The problem is that you are pointing to http://localhost:3700/api/, you should point to you host. The localhost is a default name that enables you to test programs in your pc.

Comment: @HanielBaez  excuse my ignorance, I don't have much knowledge about databases and many of the courses do not teach how to mount on a page, what should I go instead of that localhost? Should the address that appears in index.js (mongoose.connect ('mongodb: // leandro: prueba123 @ cluster0 ....) ?

Comment: Try this: `export var Global = {
  url: 'https://nnoticias-3000b.web.app/api/'
};`

Comment: aqui todos estamos aprendiendo.